# Get Strings from JSONArray to String[] or List<String> for input into an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, string

I have this JSON code and have succesfully created objects for other keys but the "authors" key is causing me problems. I have retrieved the data into a single String but it contained unwanted characters so formatted it in my Adapter class, but I feel this is sloppy.

Here is a snippet of the JSON

```
    {  
   "kind":"books#volumes",
   "totalItems":2816,
   "items":[  
      {  
         "kind":"books#volume",
         "id":"6tLAyQLSzG0C",
         "etag":"N70szFickpY",
         "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/6tLAyQLSzG0C",
         "volumeInfo":{  
            "title":"Android for Work",
            "subtitle":"Productivity for Professionals",
            "authors":[  
               "Marziah Karch"
            ],
            "publisher":"Apress",
            "publishedDate":"2010-09-01",
```

Here is my method for retrieving the data from the JSON results -

```
public static ArrayList<Books> extractBooks(String jsonString) {
        ArrayList<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();
        String title;
        String[] authors;
        String published;
        String description;
        String url;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        JSONObject imageLinks = null;

        try {
            JSONObject baseJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray jsonArray = baseJsonObject.getJSONArray("items");


            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i ++) {
                JSONObject currentBook = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject items = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                JSONArray authorArray = items.getJSONArray("authors");
                authors = new String[authorArray.length()];
                for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray.length(); a++) {
                    authors[a]= jsonArray.getString("authors");
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "String[] authors: " + authors);
                }
//TODO: Fixed? Keep testing.
                if (items.has("imageLinks")) {
                imageLinks = items.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
                    String image = imageLinks.getString("smallThumbnail");
                    bitmap = extractImages(image);
                } else {
                    bitmap = extractImages("http://books.google.com/books/content?id=M_bMehaHiG0C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api");
                }

                Boolean hasCover = items.has("imageLinks");
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "has imageLinks - " + hasCover.toString());



                if (items.has("title")){
                    title = items.getString("title");
                } else {
                    title = "No title available";
                }
                //TODO: Fix authors value to "list" or "array" rather than patching with String.replace in BooksAdapter
//                if (author.has("authors")){
//                    author = items.toString("authors");
//                } else {
//                    author = ("No author available");
//                }
                if (items.has("publishedDate")) {
                    published = items.getString("publishedDate");
                } else {
                    published = null;
                }
                if (items.has("description")){
                    description = items.getString("description");
                } else {
                    description = "No description available";
                }
                if (items.has("infoLink")) {
                    url = items.getString("infoLink");
                } else {
                    url = "none";
                }
                //TODO:Add key for ebook:True||False so can add icon over cover for Google Play Books




                Books book = new Books(title, bitmap, published, description, url, authors);
                books.add(book);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem parsing JSON book results", e);
        }

        return books;
    }
```

As you can see this is work in progress! I am trying to create a `for` loop to loop through the "authors" key and save the results in a String[]. It is not working, I get an error "No value for authors". I can see that once I've gone to that key, I have no value to reference, but I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: i suggest to you to take a class in input that has the same structure of your json, so it bind it automatically!

Comment: The Google Books API guide says it's a List, so, List then? I tried but got all kinds of errors. I'll look at this again after I try to implement Pavneet's idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
authors":[  // your json array
               "Marziah Karch"
            ],
```

so `authors` contains string values so you should retrieve them using index `a`

you need to use

```
authors[a] = authorArray.getString(a);
// i recommend to use optString as authorArray.optString(a);
```

Comment: `authorArray.getString(a)`, not `jsonArray.getString(a)`

Comment: Ah, of course, thank you! I should have realised I needed to use the indices to reference the array objects. Excellent, I've got the Strings now to format them properly. Many thanks :)

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding